# jQuery - How can i make this trigger work, so that i have the value 100?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

How can i trigger click and get the value 100? (trigger click is working but alert does not show that value 100).

```
// Manually clicked 
$('.clickhere').live("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.triggerclick').trigger('click'); 
});


// Trigger click 
$(".triggerclick").live("click", function() {

  var root = $(this);
  var id = root.find(".test").text();   // should show 100 
  alert(id);

  return false;
});

<!-- based on this structure -->
<div class="triggerclick">
  <img class="left"/>
  <div class="left">
    <div>    </div>
    <div>    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>        
        <li> 
          <a>
            <span class="clickhere">Main Click is here</span>
          </a>          
        </li>        
      </ul>
    </div>    
    <div>     </div>
    <div>     </div>
  </div>


  <code class="test">100</code>

</div>
```

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rQZWH/

Comment: Have you tested it in different browsers? I get the 100 prompt when i click it in Google Chrome (version 17.0.963.78 m).

Comment: How strange, here its not working still the same logic.

Comment: @edmastermind29: jsfiddle.net is working in Chrome/ Opera/ Firefox/ Midori.

Comment: I was appeasing gdoron (but I find it funny how you didnt mention IE) and I'm sure you're not going to end up implementing this code using jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example seems to be working just fine but why this?

```
$('.clickhere').live("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.triggerclick').trigger('click'); 
});
```

When you can do:

```
$('document').on('click', '.clickhere', function(){
  $(this).parents('.triggerclick').trigger('click'); 
});
```

`live()` is deprecated, `on()` is the new guy.

Comment: i am using latest jQuery libraries. But in my code i replaced all from .live to .on but does not work as click event patcher (like it was with .live) .

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
(anonymous function)`

Comment: make sure you're using jQ 1.7+

Comment: /*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */  YES but i get that error.

Comment: +1. Note that your delegate event is **wrong**, you didn't pass a selector, so it's a simple event callback.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/99KHB/